# Smell coming from my iMac fan vent

Tags: imac

While tidying up some cables behind my Late-2013 iMac, I noticed a funny smell coming from the fan vent. Something similar to warm wax or maybe plastic – something chemical.

I did some research, and read of cases where burning smell would be coming from the vent, but this isn't really like that. In fact:

1. The smell isn't that strong, I only noticed it by getting close to the back of the computer, I couldn't smell it in the room, or during normal use.
2. The smell isn't typical of burning material. It's more similar to hair removal wax (*yep!*).

I tried to vacuum the vent, and I also let the fans spin fast for a bit (using a dedicated software) but the smell is still there and it's more obvious when the fans spin fast.

What could it be? Is it anything dangerous for me health wise? 
Or is it instead something common that I just didn't notice before?

Comment: Until you open it up and trace the smell, a wild guess is all that we can do.  I can guarantee, however, that Apple didn’t use wax or hair remover in the assembly of the iMac.

Comment: @Allan, of course they didn't – I used the wax example to describe the type of smell. If I wanted to open the computer or have a 100% correct answer I would have had the machine serviced. A (possibly informed) guess, as wild as it could be, is all I asked for.